# help solving 1st order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Here's the equation that's plaguing me:
$$xy'-y-x \sin \left(\frac yx\right) =0$$

I've tried u substitution using $y=ux$ and ended up getting: $$\frac 1x\left[\ln \left(\left|\sin \left(\frac yx\right)\right|\over \cos\left(\frac yx\right)+1\right)+1\right]=c$$ (and solving for y yields something ridiculous)

The answer from the textbook is: $$y=2x\arctan cx$$
Does anyone have any ideas what I could be doing wrong? If necessary, I can post a jpg of the steps I took to arrive at this solution (because it takes me forever to get everything typed out correctly here).

Comment: That's equal to what, $u$?

Comment: Sorry, Mike. I let $y=ux$, so I plugged in $ux$ everywhere there's a $y$ in the original equation, and I plugged in $u dx + y du$ for $dy$. Does that help?

Comment: You said you plugged that substitution into your differential equation and ended up with something that was not an equation.

Comment: Oops! I'll edit it to fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that (just by direct calculation)
$$
x y' - y = x^2 \left( \frac{y}{x} \right)'.
$$
Hence, you get
$$
x^2 \left( \frac{y}{x} \right)' - x \sin(\frac{y}{x}) = 0,
$$
i.e.
$$
x \left( \frac{y}{x} \right)' = \sin(\frac{y}{x}).
$$
Substituting $\frac{y}{x} = u$, you get
$$
x u' = \sin(u).
$$
Now it can be treated by separation of variables.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you break down how you arrive at the first equation? I'm not really very mathematical, so what would be obvious to most people isn't to me...

Comment: $\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)' = \frac{x y' - y}{x^2}$, by quotient rule (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_rule). Hence, multiplying by $x^2$, you get $x^2 \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)' = x y' - y$

Comment: @jane You should be getting the same thing after your substitution.

Comment: Okay, I'm still pretty lost. Starting with $x dy -\left[y+x \sin \left(\frac yx \right) \right]dx$ and using the $y=xu$ and $dy=u dx + x du$ substitutions, I ended up with $x^2 du=x \sin u dx$ as an intermediate step... Is this along the same lines as what you did here?

Comment: Ah, I see it is exactly what you did. So, somewhere after this I went wrong... but I have no idea where.

Answer (score 1):

If $y=xu$, then $\frac{dy}{dx}=x\frac{du}{dx}+u$.  Dividing your DE by $x$ yields

$$y'-\frac yx-\sin\frac yx=0$$
$$xu'+u-u-\sin u=0$$
$$xu'=\sin u$$

Comment: Thanks. I feel silly for not catching that simplification earlier. I'm working on it now.

Comment: So, flipping it around and integrating both sides, I end up with $$\ln\left(\frac{\left|\sin u|}{\cos u +1}\right)=\ln\left|x\right| + c$$, then e-ing both sides and back substituting, I end up with $\s\left(\frac yx\right) = cx$. Then I tried to solve for $y$ and floundered until I put it into wolfram alpha, where I found that my LHS$=\tan \left(\frac{y}{2x}\right)$, and from *there* the correct answer fell out! Thank you both @Mike and @Voliar!

Comment: Ran out of time trying to fix that comment, here's what it should have said:

So, flipping it around and integrating both sides, I end up with $$\ln\left(\frac{\left|\sin u\right|}{\cos u +1}\right)=\ln\left|x\right| + c,$$ then e-ing both sides and back substituting, all that's left is to solve for $y$. This is where I floundered until I put it into wolfram alpha, where I found that my LHS$=\tan \left(\frac{y}{2x}\right)$, and from *there* the correct answer fell out! Thank you both @Mike and @Voliar!